# How to create a cache server with osx server?

Tags: network, osx-server

We have an OS X server in a small office and want to have a cache server. When first user download something from Internet (`NOT just from apple products`) the second it should be downloaded from the server cache not from Internet.

With this approach we want to use less bandwidth and faster downloads. What approach should I take to achieve this mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS X Cache server is for caching only Apple products. For having web caching you can try something like [Squidman](http://squidman.net/squidman/)